# Two way repeated measure anova on multiple columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, testing, multiple-columns, anova

I would like to perform a two way repeated ANOVA in r on multiple columns in a dataframe.

I have tried few techniques but always get an error message. I have looked on various forums but I can't find anything about applying it to various columns (it's only on one variable). I have been trying to find an answer for few days now and I start to be a little bit desperate. Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks

For a one way anova it works great:

```
anovatest<-function(x) {aov (x ~ group, data=finalds1)}

results_anova<-apply(finalds1[4:11], 2, anovatest)
results_anova
summary(results_anova[[2]])
tuk<-tukey_hsd(results_anova[[2]])
tuk
```

but not for a two way repeated (error message)

```
anovatestpaired<- function(x) {
        anova_test(data = finalds1, dv = x, wid=id, between = group, within = time)
}
ranovapaired<-apply(finalds1[4:11], 2,anovatestpaired)
```

Reproducible df:

````
finalds1=structure(list(id = structure(c(54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 73L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 73L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L), levels = c("M01", "M02", 
"M03", "M04", "M05", "M06", "M07", "M08", "M09", "M10", "M11", 
"M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20", 
"M21", "M22", "M23", "M24", "M25", "M26", "M27", "M28", "M29", 
"M30", "M31", "M32", "M33", "M34", "M35", "M36", "M37", "M38", 
"M39", "M40", "M41", "M42", "M43", "M44", "M45", "M46", "M47", 
"M48", "M49", "M50", "M51", "M52", "M53", "SA01", "SA02", "SA03", 
"SA04", "SA05", "SA06", "SA07", "SA08", "SA09", "SA10", "SA100", 
"SA101", "SA102", "SA103", "SA104", "SA105", "SA107", "SA108", 
"SA109", "SA11", "SA110", "SA111", "SA112", "SA113", "SA114", 
"SA115", "SA116", "SA118", "SA12", "SA13", "SA14", "SA15", "SA16", 
"SA17", "SA18", "SA19", "SA20", "SA21", "SA22", "SA23", "SA24", 
"SA25", "SA26", "SA27", "SA28", "SA29", "SA30", "SA31", "SA32", 
"SA33", "SA34", "SA35", "SA36", "SA37", "SA38", "SA39", "SA40", 
"SA41", "SA42", "SA43", "SA44", "SA45", "SA46", "SA47", "SA48", 
"SA49", "SA50", "SA51", "SA52", "SA53", "SA54", "SA56", "SA57", 
"SA58", "SA59", "SA60", "SA61", "SA62", "SA63", "SA64", "SA65", 
"SA66", "SA67", "SA68", "SA69", "SA72", "SA73", "SA74", "SA75", 
"SA76", "SA77", "SA78", "SA79", "SA80", "SA81", "SA82", "SA83", 
"SA84", "SA85", "SA86", "SA87", "SA88", "SA89", "SA90", "SA92", 
"SA93", "SA94", "SA95", "SA96", "SA97", "SA99", "SC01", "SC02", 
"SC03", "SC04", "SC05", "SC06", "SC07", "SC08", "SC09", "SC10", 
"SC11", "SC12", "SC13", "SC14", "SC15", "SC16", "SC17", "SC18", 
"SC19", "SC20", "SC21", "SC22", "SC23", "SC24", "SC25", "SC26", 
"SC27", "SC28", "SC29", "SC30", "SC31", "SC32", "SC33", "SC34", 
"SC35", "SC36", "SC37", "SC38"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Metab", "SA", "SC"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    whz = structure(c(-0.43, 1.55, -0.19, 0.94, 0.87, 0.32, 1.97, 
    1.54, 1.68, 1.79, 1.25, 0.78, -0.86, 1.75, 0.28, 2.02, 3.14, 
    1.67, 1.03, 2.21, 0.02, 2.83, -0.36, -0.1, -0.02, -0.7, 0.33, 
    0.26, 1, 0.28, 0.92, 1.53, 0.69, 1.16, 1.64, 0.57, 1.57, 
    1.15, 2.46, 0.31, 0.48, 2.24, 1.22, 0.94, 0.11, 0.02, 0.71, 
    -1.21, 1.17, 2.93, 1.01, 2.02, 0.78, 0.79, -1.19, 0.62, -0.7, 
    0.85, 0.6, 0.71, 1.35, 1.04, 0.38, 0.44, 2.04, 1.07, 0.78, 
    0.04, 3.28, 2.2, 2.03, 2.15, -0.84, 0.84, 1.44, 1.79, -0.2, 
    0.5, 1.97, 0.69, -0.09, 0.37, 2.4, 0.81, 1.72, 3.03, 1.49, 
    1.83, -0.09, -1.05, 0.47, 0.93, 1.76, 0.7, -0.65, 0.17, 0.63, 
    1.07, 2.34, 0.97, 1.22, 0.38, 2.38, 0.58, -1.02, 2.13, 0.74, 
    1.91, 4.58, 1.85, 0.62, 1.56, 0.82, 3.11, 0.23, -0.28, 1.27, 
    1.78, 0.73, 0.66, 2.28, 0.07, 1.39, 0.76, 0.85, 0.19, 0.13, 
    0.38, 2.25, 0.39, 1.32, 1.98, 1.04, 0.18, 0.44, -1.06, -0.02, 
    -1.44, 0.68, 2.01, 0.15, 0.98, 1.56, 0.82, 2.77, 0.55, 1.25, 
    1.52, 2.84, 3.08, 1.68, 0.94, 1.17, 0.66, 0.92, 0.24, 0.73, 
    1.65, 0.23, 1.45, 0.77, 1.44, 0.8, -0.36, 0.62, 0.61, -0.31, 
    0.72, 1.65, -0.45, 0.48, 2.55, 1.95, 1.12, 2.29, 2.42, 2.41, 
    4.02, -0.21, 2.22, 1.43, 0.4, 1.07, 0.25, 1.65, 1.81, -0.13, 
    0.37, 1.95, 0.62, -0.02, 1.55, 1.67, 2.79, 1.36, 0.38, 0.99, 
    0.81, 0.58, -1.18, 0.48, 1.45, -0.82, 1.62, -0.2, 1.08, 0.76, 
    -0.7, 1.76, 1.45, 1.78, 1.6, 1.07, 0.79, -0.92, 1.83, 0.48, 
    2.21, 3.22, 0.91, 0.8, 2.09, -0.06, 2.34, -0.38, -0.1, -0.2, 
    -0.86, 0.26, 0.38, 0.88, 0.39, 0.54, 1.32, 0.34, 0.97, 2.48, 
    0.26, 1.81, 1.13, 2.17, 0.31, 0.57, 2.28, 0.91, 0.77, 0.16, 
    -0.02, -0.64, -1.18, 1, 3.08, 0.65, 1.73, 0.82, 0.84, -1.17, 
    0.51, -0.43, 0.78, 0.55, 1.08, 1.85, 1, 0.26, 0.41, 2.2, 
    1.03, 0.79, -0.2, 3.03, 2.37, 2.16, 2.13, -0.84, 0.77, 1.32, 
    1.85, -0.22, 0.42, 2.24, 0.35, -0.22, 0.24, 2.06, 0.75, 1.92, 
    2.57, 1.48, 2.02, -0.58, -1.17, 0.51, 0.77, 1.75, 0.5, -0.7, 
    0.73, 0.35, 0.8, 2.17, 1, 1.13, 1.08, 2.03, 0.69, -1.19, 
    2.01, 0.93, 2.03, 3.11, 2.13, 0.79, 1.72, 0.81, 3.04, 0.27, 
    -0.54, 1.12, 1.77, 0.5, 0.81, 2.76, -0.1, 1.3, 1.05, 0.74, 
    0.01, 0.27, 0.28, 2.23, 0.1, 1.18, 2.29, 0.44, -0.1, 0.59, 
    -1.03, -0.2, -1.71, 0.56, 2.29, 1.16, 0.43, 1.6, 2.34, 2.66, 
    0.22, 1, 1.68, 2.27, 2.89, 1.68, 0.81, 1.05, 0.79, 1.05, 
    0.7, 0.73, 1.85, 0.44, 1.23, 0.69, 1.32, 0.75, -0.34, -0.12, 
    0.55, -0.23, 0.82, 1.39, -0.36, 0.33, 2.6, 1.67, 1.03, 2.49, 
    2.18, 2.32, 4.21, -0.36, 2.04, 1.57, 0.59, 1.47, 0.08, 1.62, 
    1.65, -0.29, 0.25, 2.13, 0.6, 0.09, 1.42, 1.59, 2.83, 1.18, 
    0.61, 1, 0.82, 0.49, -1.3, 0.49, 1.47), label = "Weight/Length", format.spss = "F5.2", display_width = 11L), 
    haz = structure(c(-0.41, 1.55, -0.17, 0.93, 0.87, -0.62, 
    1.98, 1.53, 1.67, 1.87, 0.35, 0.77, -0.86, 1.74, 0.28, 2.01, 
    3.13, 1.67, 1.03, 2.2, 0.01, 2.83, -0.37, -0.05, -0.03, -0.7, 
    0.32, -0.73, 0.99, 0.28, 0.81, 1.42, 0.56, 1, 2.58, 0.44, 
    1.43, 1, 2.3, 0.19, 0.32, 2.24, 1.22, 1.01, 0.11, 0.02, -0.72, 
    -1.22, 1.16, 2.93, 1.01, 2.02, 0.78, 0.78, -1.19, 0.61, -0.71, 
    0.84, 0.58, 0.7, 1.34, 1.03, 0.37, 0.49, 2.04, 1.06, 0.78, 
    0.03, 3.27, 2.19, 2.02, 2.62, -0.85, 0.84, 1.43, 1.78, -0.21, 
    0.49, 1.97, 0.68, -0.1, 0.36, 2.39, 0.8, 1.71, 3.14, 1.54, 
    1.82, -0.1, -1.05, 0.46, 0.92, 1.75, 0.69, -0.66, 0.17, 0.62, 
    1.06, 2.33, 1.02, 1.21, 0.58, 2.37, 0.57, -1, 2.12, 0.73, 
    1.91, 4.57, 1.71, 0.62, 1.63, 0.85, 3.12, 0.24, -0.29, 1.26, 
    1.78, 0.48, 0.67, 2.3, 0.06, 1.38, 0.78, 0.85, 0.2, 0.15, 
    0.37, 2.24, 0.39, 1.31, 1.97, 1.04, 0.17, 0.43, -1.07, -0.03, 
    -1.45, 0.67, 2, 0.01, 0.82, 1.43, 0.7, 2.6, 0.41, 1.13, 1.39, 
    2.75, 3.1, 1.69, 1.07, 1.26, 0.71, 1, 0.24, 0.99, 1.66, 0.43, 
    1.46, 0.82, 1.39, 0.82, -0.29, -0.36, 0.83, 0.03, 0.67, 1.66, 
    -0.36, 0.47, 2.6, 1.89, 1.14, 2.24, 2.25, 2.5, 4.08, -0.22, 
    2.27, 1.43, 0.32, 1.1, 0.21, 1.75, 1.76, -0.13, 0.41, 2, 
    0.62, 0.01, 1.63, 1.6, 2.78, 1.38, 0.34, 0.99, 0.74, 0.65, 
    -1.09, 0.49, 1.37, -0.41, 1.55, -0.17, 0.93, 0.87, -0.62, 
    1.98, 1.53, 1.67, 1.87, 0.35, 0.77, -0.86, 1.74, 0.28, 2.01, 
    3.13, 1.67, 1.03, 2.2, 0.01, 2.83, -0.37, -0.05, -0.03, -0.7, 
    0.32, -0.73, 0.99, 0.28, 0.81, 1.42, 0.56, 1, 2.58, 0.44, 
    1.43, 1, 2.3, 0.19, 0.32, 2.24, 1.22, 1.01, 0.11, 0.02, -0.72, 
    -1.22, 1.16, 2.93, 1.01, 2.02, 0.78, 0.78, -1.19, 0.61, -0.71, 
    0.84, 0.58, 0.7, 1.34, 1.03, 0.37, 0.49, 2.04, 1.06, 0.78, 
    0.03, 3.27, 2.19, 2.02, 2.62, -0.85, 0.84, 1.43, 1.78, -0.21, 
    0.49, 1.97, 0.68, -0.1, 0.36, 2.39, 0.8, 1.71, 3.14, 1.54, 
    1.82, -0.1, -1.05, 0.46, 0.92, 1.75, 0.69, -0.66, 0.17, 0.62, 
    1.06, 2.33, 1.02, 1.21, 0.58, 2.37, 0.57, -1, 2.12, 0.73, 
    1.91, 4.57, 1.71, 0.62, 0.85, 3.12, 0.24, -0.29, 1.26, 1.78, 
    0.48, 0.67, 2.3, 0.06, 1.38, 0.78, 0.85, 0.2, 0.15, 0.37, 
    2.24, 0.39, 1.31, 1.97, 1.04, 0.17, 0.43, -1.07, -0.03, -1.45, 
    0.67, 2, 0.01, 0.82, 1.43, 0.7, 2.6, 0.41, 1.13, 1.39, 2.75, 
    2.02, 3.1, 1.69, 1.07, 1.26, 0.71, 1, 0.24, 0.99, 1.66, 0.43, 
    1.46, 0.82, 1.39, 0.82, -0.29, -0.36, 0.83, 0.03, 0.67, 1.66, 
    -0.36, 0.47, 2.6, 1.89, 1.14, 2.24, 2.25, 2.5, 4.08, -0.22, 
    2.27, 1.43, 0.32, 1.1, 0.21, 1.75, 1.76, -0.13, 0.41, 2, 
    0.62, 0.01, 1.63, 1.6, 2.78, 1.38, 0.34, 0.99, 0.74, 0.65, 
    -1.09, 0.49, 1.37), label = "Length/Age", format.spss = "F5.2", display_width = 9L), 
    wc = structure(c(75, 72, 60.5, 82.3, 88.5, 76, 97.5, 81, 
    87, 88, 84, 76, 85.6, 101.8, 85.5, 84.6, 89, 65, 78.1, 87, 
    90, 90.8, 90.2, 84.2, 76, 94, 82.5, 80, 75.1, 89, 80.7, 76, 
    84.2, 95, 82.7, 70.7, 88, 80.2, 90.5, 86, 75.7, 96, 110, 
    68, 78, 67, 88, 84, 84.4, 88.5, 73, 94.6, 73.5, 83.5, 83.2, 
    83.6, 80.8, 75, 85.6, 99.9, 88.8, 69.5, 65.8, 114.8, 67, 
    82, 69.4, 84.8, 86.4, 78.4, 85.5, 96, 84.8, 77, 80, 101, 
    82, 85.5, 83, 83, 87, 63, 85, 76, 78, 92, 89.5, 84, 87, 68, 
    82, 88, 90, 79, 89, 90, 72, 87, 95, 84, 67, 82, 90, 71, 94, 
    75, 98.5, 116, 104.2, 77, 86, 71.2, 82, 92.2, 77.2, 67, 85, 
    80, 80.7, 84.5, 100, 82, 89.3, 81, 70, 83.3, 68.8, 75.8, 
    83.3, 93.2, 80, 78.5, 79, 73.7, 70, 70.5, 70.5, 65, 79, 77, 
    78, 79.7, 83, 84, 91, 73.6, 76.6, 83.2, 82.5, 80, 80, 73, 
    67, 90, 83, 77.5, 74, 104, 82, 89, 76, 88, 77.5, 70, 79, 
    76, 79, 97, 74, 61, 73, 89.5, 77, 96, 89.5, 91.5, 80, 104, 
    74.5, 77.5, 93, 80, 82, 65, 98, 92.5, 79, 83.5, 95, 80.2, 
    83.5, 91.5, 84, 86.5, 87, 94, 67.5, 74.5, 82.5, 68, 86, 81.5, 
    83, 76.1, 61.2, 88.5, 85.1, 86, 101.3, 85.5, 88, 95.3, 80.4, 
    71, 80.5, 91.5, 78, 79, 90, 78.5, 84.5, 84.5, 89.7, 82, 84, 
    84, 74, 74, 82, 81.5, 73, 76, 82.5, 72, 91.5, 89, 82, 67, 
    86, 81.5, 87, 90.5, 73, 95.5, 105, 65.8, 79, 77.2, 82.2, 
    79.5, 78.5, 91.5, 68, 94.5, 77.4, 90, 68, 90, 79, 85.6, 89.3, 
    89.3, 78.4, 78.4, 70, 79, 95, 83.3, 100, 81, 91, 76, 71.5, 
    84, 78, 72, 73, 99, 89, 95, 89, 85, 85, 61, 84.4, 74, 82, 
    91.5, 93, 86, 92, 64, 79, 84.8, 90, 77, 66, 92, 87, 87, 89, 
    86, 65, 81, 80, 82.5, 71.6, 96, 78.1, 67, 80, 81, 77.5, 75, 
    88, 93.5, 78, 71.6, 89, 80.2, 84.2, 87.5, 95, 72, 90, 74.5, 
    70.5, 89, 67.8, 90.5, 85.5, 90, 82, 78.5, 73, 76, 70, 66.5, 
    74, 64.5, 81.5, 69, 84, 77, 81, 89.5, 88, 68.5, 72, 71.5, 
    83.5, 80, 65.8, 73, 65.5, 88, 94.5, 73, 73, 105, 76.5, 86, 
    71, 89, 80, 66, 76, 77.3, 78, 93, 76, 90, 73.5, 86, 75.5, 
    101, 91.5, 90, 80.5, 100, 69, 75.5, 83, 80, 78, 59, 101.5, 
    76.1, 84.8, 79.7, 95.5, 75, 88, 88, 84, 79, 80, 89, 69, 68.5, 
    76, 63, 83, 78), format.spss = "F5.2", display_width = 11L), 
    totalcholesterol = structure(c(166, 172, 229, 209, 171, 211, 
    140, 161, 131, 195, 157, 149, 151, 145, 165, 163, 126, 146, 
    113, 122, 184, 202, 196, 197, 179, 199, 185, 151, 161, 162, 
    165, 164, 161, 156, 153, 199, 156, 155, 160, 163, 209, 173, 
    125, 194, 170, 226, 197, 159, 122, 112, 199, 122, 163, 154, 
    194, 146, 138, 194, 149, 174, 125, 156, 163, 200, 142, 150, 
    163, 199, 118, 147, 163, 147, 157, 173, 170, 217, 127, 249, 
    158, 201, 170, 189, 149, 172, 184, 129, 148, 123, 186, 168, 
    141, 172, 108, 155, 164, 130, 152, 150, 72, 121, 180, 155, 
    156, 191, 151, 203, 146, 152, 186, 221, 172, 210, 174, 120, 
    151, 175, 143, 180, 169, 143, 117, 142, 146, 174, 173, 158, 
    197, 120, 128, 144, 172, 168, 211, 211, 226, 192, 179, 135, 
    185, 110, 165, 228, 175, 178, 150, 173, 161, 112, 131, 181, 
    166, 134, 163, 151, 175, 195, 190, 124, 159, 161, 115, 122, 
    173, 190, 145, 168, 199, 174, 159, 167, 155, 182, 167, 168, 
    199, 126, 144, 139, 162, 208, 132, 139, 154, 165, 188, 188, 
    130, 214, 150, 146, 178, 158, 165, 148, 171, 197, 160, 145, 
    171, 188, 168, 209, 156, 156, 207, 226, 151, 168, 159, 194, 
    161, 225, 140, 141, 173, 150, 134, 133, 121, 226, 168, 125, 
    184, 153, 167, 191, 149, 228, 129, 149, 176, 162, 171, 144, 
    162, 155, 173, 166, 147, 139, 156, 173, 146, 182, 134, 190, 
    161, 161, 224, 142, 113, 164, 200, 140, 141, 168, 184, 212, 
    130, 197, 163, 171, 138, 194, 155, 175, 130, 125, 179, 188, 
    148, 144, 161, 145, 161, 177, 188, 169, 186, 197, 125, 153, 
    193, 200, 165, 176, 185, 113, 150, 12, 163, 166, 115, 158, 
    122, 143, 184, 143, 157, 176, 163, 113, 149, 161, 235, 163, 
    199, 182, 113, 125, 158, 170, 192, 235, 155, 114, 155, 186, 
    146, 144, 171, 183, 113, 128, 144, 146, 182, 168, 179, 166, 
    100, 131, 225, 158, 192, 192, 201, 164, 149, 156, 171, 113, 
    125, 166, 182, 151, 146, 175, 172, 112, 129, 171, 183, 156, 
    184, 202, 147, 176, 186, 120, 168, 178, 165, 148, 190, 228, 
    140, 168, 178, 171, 161, 155, 185, 168, 174, 199, 271, 146, 
    165, 164, 168, 195, 163, 147, 158, 130, 212, 127, 159, 212, 
    183, 179, 189, 164, 180, 137, 192, 192, 181, 105, 150, 202, 
    202, 192), format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 11L), ldl = structure(c(100, 
    104, 171, 153, 107, 152, 87, 101, 70, 137, 96, 95, 98, 94, 
    92, 102, 63, 104, 62, 75, 125, 117, 114, 132, 112, 146, 121, 
    91, 113, 120, 96, 96, 95, 87, 96, 134, 98, 92, 88, 101, 133, 
    113, 77, 128, 97, 169, 136, 96, 74, 59, 121, 66, 109, 103, 
    116, 86, 87, 124, 88, 94, 77, 98, 90, 133, 79, 78, 98, 129, 
    62, 62, 96, 72, 85, 98, 101, 132, 69, 196, 76, 125, 105, 
    108, 89, 108, 123, 51, 92, 50, 121, 105, 80, 103, 59, 96, 
    89, 65, 77, 90, 92, 65, 123, 96, 80, 128, 92, 124, 96, 83, 
    120, 145, 114, 134, 116, 65, 91, 103, 84, 123, 99, 96, 61, 
    82, 85, 116, 116, 113, 121, 69, 82, 100, 108, 99, 144, 152, 
    158, 128, 112, 89, 119, 61, 99, 147, 109, 121, 92, 115, 95, 
    62, 72, 130, 96, 76, 117, 96, 108, 131, 120, 67, 99, 105, 
    63, 63, 103, 128, 92, 120, 146, 106, 103, 94, 85, 122, 111, 
    102, 143, 74, 87, 80, 67, 140, 85, 87, 101, 94, 122, 124, 
    82, 150, 92, 84, 119, 98, 89, 97, 117, 122, 111, 86, 90, 
    110, 107, 150, 103, 94, 149, 159, 91, 98, 109, 126, 98, 167, 
    77, 90, 103, 80, 68, 75, 55, 153, 98, 74, 113, 80, 102, 116, 
    84, 158, 66, 85, 114, 111, 101, 95, 92, 86, 96, 90, 92, 77, 
    91, 108, 86, 118, 85, 127, 99, 92, 160, 80, 63, 92, 123, 
    86, 94, 92, 120, 149, 69, 120, 108, 111, 69, 122, 86, 106, 
    72, 63, 122, 97, 67, 70, 85, 70, 96, 102, 117, 101, 119, 
    146, 70, 94, 122, 122, 94, 110, 121, 39, 72, 48, 109, 110, 
    60, 95, 65, 83, 114, 79, 87, 113, 103, 55, 95, 92, 160, 89, 
    121, 104, 65, 74, 84, 105, 122, 157, 103, 56, 92, 114, 78, 
    97, 106, 117, 61, 72, 83, 91, 122, 106, 103, 89, 51, 89, 
    153, 90, 123, 132, 132, 110, 84, 84, 96, 72, 77, 104, 122, 
    92, 80, 113, 106, 62, 72, 121, 122, 102, 125, 130, 92, 111, 
    119, 66, 109, 119, 91, 92, 120, 160, 93, 117, 126, 88, 77, 
    92, 119, 115, 100, 130, 200, 79, 95, 99, 89, 123, 108, 82, 
    108, 81, 103, 63, 103, 149, 116, 115, 122, 95, 106, 89, 128, 
    118, 123, 51, 90, 130, 119, 120), label = "LDL-Cholesterol", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 11L), 
    hdl = structure(c(54, 55, 48, 38, 46, 50, 45, 38, 50, 43, 
    39, 32, 35, 34, 40, 48, 53, 33, 42, 34, 41, 48, 51, 38, 53, 
    38, 37, 44, 37, 33, 54, 47, 51, 39, 44, 54, 32, 53, 39, 36, 
    58, 41, 34, 43, 40, 49, 49, 50, 37, 36, 54, 47, 35, 40, 50, 
    44, 40, 43, 45, 41, 34, 50, 46, 46, 50, 53, 53, 45, 37, 70, 
    51, 55, 51, 58, 58, 49, 44, 37, 32, 64, 41, 63, 46, 55, 46, 
    65, 43, 55, 42, 56, 39, 50, 38, 46, 45, 53, 53, 39, 45, 47, 
    48, 32, 45, 45, 36, 60, 30, 43, 43, 57, 36, 56, 45, 40, 40, 
    61, 50, 29, 55, 38, 35, 47, 42, 50, 46, 26, 60, 33, 36, 34, 
    44, 59, 45, 44, 55, 45, 53, 38, 50, 40, 57, 46, 48, 45, 43, 
    49, 53, 39, 46, 39, 36, 39, 36, 42, 40, 50, 63, 46, 45, 39, 
    43, 30, 57, 46, 40, 39, 39, 53, 40, 54, 56, 40, 37, 48, 43, 
    29, 46, 45, 82, 31, 34, 37, 41, 63, 34, 50, 37, 51, 36, 42, 
    41, 34, 55, 40, 42, 60, 36, 38, 52, 57, 48, 48, 46, 47, 50, 
    41, 48, 60, 40, 45, 52, 43, 58, 42, 48, 44, 46, 47, 55, 55, 
    48, 38, 52, 58, 53, 31, 51, 45, 32, 51, 41, 38, 57, 36, 50, 
    41, 60, 65, 39, 52, 36, 36, 49, 43, 34, 44, 41, 51, 50, 52, 
    37, 55, 58, 45, 34, 56, 49, 32, 48, 45, 40, 58, 58, 45, 63, 
    46, 40, 47, 29, 63, 53, 59, 55, 50, 46, 58, 58, 42, 45, 31, 
    39, 48, 43, 66, 55, 51, 41, 50, 38, 46, 41, 43, 38, 48, 36, 
    46, 59, 56, 44, 46, 48, 49, 51, 49, 65, 48, 56, 45, 39, 41, 
    54, 44, 50, 63, 41, 39, 46, 58, 53, 33, 53, 48, 33, 44, 46, 
    49, 48, 44, 55, 44, 39, 32, 46, 50, 45, 47, 53, 39, 51, 61, 
    48, 32, 31, 42, 46, 41, 49, 48, 52, 39, 40, 38, 53, 31, 46, 
    48, 34, 51, 58, 43, 49, 43, 65, 41, 61, 49, 35, 37, 36, 58, 
    82, 37, 48, 38, 45, 43, 58, 31, 49, 52, 65, 32, 45, 39, 37, 
    41, 34, 49, 42, 51, 39, 48, 36, 35, 55, 38, 48, 53, 41, 39, 
    49, 63, 41, 47), label = "HDL-Cholesterol", format.spss = "F3.2", display_width = 11L), 
    glucose = structure(c(90, 95, 79, 85, 95, 97, 86, 74, 88, 
    95, 94, 88, 86, 94, 86, 95, 97, 88, 88, 88, 83, 103, 79, 
    67, 88, 79, 90, 79, 97, 94, 85, 83, 88, 97, 81, 95, 92, 94, 
    99, 79, 83, 92, 81, 92, 79, 94, 83, 79, 81, 92, 86, 95, 92, 
    95, 92, 85, 94, 81, 86, 85, 99, 92, 85, 72, 86, 81, 79, 86, 
    97, 88, 92, 97, 83, 103, 97, 95, 85, 77, 77, 83, 99, 90, 
    77, 77, 83, 92, 88, 83, 88, 86, 88, 97, 101, 99, 88, 101, 
    94, 86, 85, 83, 86, 88, 92, 94, 94, 90, 160, 94, 83, 95, 
    97, 88, 88, 95, 90, 92, 113, 104, 85, 101, 91.8, 99, 94, 
    85, 85, 83, 86, 88, 95, 79, 101, 92, 83, 90, 85, 95, 88, 
    79, 90, 79, 94, 99, 83, 85, 85, 77, 99, 81, 92, 86.4, 95.4, 
    82.8, 73.8, 81, 90, 82.8, 79.2, 90, 82.8, 91.8, 90, 84.6, 
    84.6, 84.6, 77.4, 77.4, 75.6, 88.2, 79.2, 92, 90, 113, 81, 
    81, 81, 84.6, 88.2, 73.8, 81, 81, 82.8, 79.2, 70.2, 91.8, 
    97.2, 82.8, 70.2, 91.8, 93.6, 86.4, 93.6, 73.8, 95.4, 81, 
    97.2, 77.4, 90, 82.8, 86.4, 88.2, 88.2, 73.8, 90, 92, 83, 
    86, 99, 77, 86, 81, 90, 99, 83, 86, 76, 90, 85, 90, 92, 88, 
    85, 79, 79, 94, 86, 81, 88, 95, 90, 86, 92, 85, 92, 83, 92, 
    90, 92, 95, 94, 88, 90, 86, 88, 101, 95, 92, 81, 97, 92, 
    90, 81, 92, 90, 81, 88, 88, 81, 90, 85, 95, 72, 103, 95, 
    83, 97, 85, 84.6, 94, 88, 88, 77, 85, 88, 86, 88, 106, 101, 
    88, 85, 79, 91.8, 85, 99, 92, 79, 88, 88, 95, 81, 86, 77, 
    81, 92, 97, 101, 86, 86, 88, 94, 81, 86, 85, 91.8, 85, 79, 
    93.6, 81, 90, 81, 81, 94, 113, 79, 85, 88, 95, 83, 92, 112, 
    94, 95, 108, 97, 90, 88, 86, 97, 95, 88, 90, 88, 77, 94, 
    81, 90, 79, 83, 95, 88, 81, 92, 92, 92, 88, 86, 90, 85, 85, 
    97, 81, 88, 90, 76, 77.4, 94, 83, 90, 95, 85, 92, 83, 95, 
    88, 94, 94, 88, 77, 90, 86, 92, 88, 90, 77, 95, 92, 72, 90, 
    103, 90, 85, 92, 83, 81, 94, 81, 79, 94, 85, 92, 99, 95, 
    84, 95, 72, 90, 79, 97.5, 85, 88, 79, 81, 72, 85, 88), format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 11L), 
    hba1c = structure(c(5.2, 5.3, 5.3, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5, 4.9, 
    5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.5, 5.2, 5.1, 5.2, 5, 5.5, 5.4, 
    5.2, 5.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.3, 5.5, 5.2, 5.1, 5.2, 
    5.3, 5.6, 5.3, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.1, 5.2, 5.5, 5.6, 5.5, 
    5.5, 5.6, 5.2, 5.7, 4.7, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 5.2, 5.1, 5.2, 5.1, 
    5.3, 5.4, 5.1, 5.1, 5, 5.1, 5, 5.1, 5.6, 5.2, 5, 4.8, 5.2, 
    4.9, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 5.3, 5.4, 5, 5.1, 4.9, 5.1, 5.6, 5.2, 
    5.1, 5, 5, 5.5, 5, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 5.5, 5.3, 5.5, 5.1, 
    5.4, 5.5, 5.3, 5.3, 5.5, 5.3, 5.5, 5.1, 5.6, 5.4, 5.2, 7, 
    5.3, 5.1, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.5, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.5, 5.5, 5.1, 5.7, 
    5.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.1, 5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.6, 5.2, 
    5.5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.5, 5.5, 4.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.4, 5.2, 5.2, 5.5, 
    5.3, 5.1, 5.4, 5.6, 5.5, 5.7, 5.8, 5.5, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.8, 
    5.3, 5.8, 5.3, 5.7, 5.8, 5.6, 5.4, 5.5, 5.4, 5.1, 5.3, 5.7, 
    5.5, 5.6, 5, 5.4, 5.1, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.4, 5.3, 5.6, 5.1, 
    5.2, 5.1, 5.3, 5.4, 5.4, 5.1, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.3, 5.5, 5.1, 
    5.3, 5.2, 5, 4.9, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4, 5, 5.1, 4.9, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 
    5.4, 5.3, 5, 5, 4.7, 5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.2, 5.3, 5.5, 5.2, 5.3, 
    5.3, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.2, 5.3, 5.3, 5.7, 5.2, 5.2, 
    5.3, 5, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4, 5.5, 5.3, 5.2, 5.4, 5.5, 5.2, 5.1, 
    5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.4, 5.4, 5.5, 5.2, 5.6, 4.9, 5.1, 5.2, 4.9, 
    5.5, 5.1, 5, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5.4, 5.5, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.4, 
    5.5, 5.5, 5.4, 5.1, 5, 5.2, 4.9, 5.2, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.2, 
    5.1, 5, 5.2, 5.5, 5.2, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 5.6, 5, 5.4, 5.1, 5, 
    5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.1, 5.2, 
    4.9, 5.5, 5, 5.5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.2, 5.4, 4.9, 4.9, 5.4, 5.2, 
    5.1, 5.3, 5.4, 5.2, 4.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5.1, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.4, 
    5, 5.1, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 5.2, 5.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 4.6, 
    5.2, 5.3, 5.1, 5.3, 5, 5, 5.2, 5, 5.5, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 5, 
    5.3, 5.2, 5.4, 5.3, 5.3, 4.9, 5.3, 4.9, 5.5, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 
    5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1, 5.3, 5.3, 5.5, 5.3, 5.6, 5.5, 
    5.4, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 5.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.1, 5.2, 5.4, 5.2, 4.9, 
    5.1, 5.4, 5, 5.3, 5, 5.2, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 4.9, 5.3, 5.2, 5.1, 
    5.2, 4.9), format.spss = "F3.2", display_width = 11L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-404L), reshapeLong = list(varying = list(c("age_1", "age_2"), 
    c("whz_1", "whz_2"), c("haz_1", "haz_2"), c("waz_1", "waz_2"
    ), c("zbmi_1", "zbmi_2"), c("wc_1", "wc_2"), c("abc_1", "abc_2"
    ), c("PA_1", "PA_2"), c("PAextra_1", "PAextra_2"), c("TVweekdays_1", 
    "TVweekdays_2"), c("TVweekend_1", "TVweekend_2"), c("kidmed_1", 
    "kidmed_2"), c("totalcholesterol_1", "totalcholesterol_2"
    ), c("ldl_1", "ldl_2"), c("hdl_1", "hdl_2"), c("triglycerides_1", 
    "triglycerides_2"), c("glucose_1", "glucose_2"), c("insuline_1", 
    "insuline_2"), c("hba1c_1", "hba1c_2"), c("homair_1", "homair_2"
    ), c("fatmass_1", "fatmass_2"), c("energykcal_1", "energykcal_2"
    ), c("protein_1", "protein_2"), c("proteinpc_1", "proteinpc_2"
    ), c("carbohydrates_1", "carbohydrates_2"), c("carbohydratespc_1", 
    "carbohydratespc_2"), c("sugar_1", "sugar_2"), c("sugarpc_1", 
    "sugarpc_2"), c("starch_1", "starch_2"), c("fruitportions_1", 
    "fruitportions_2"), c("vegetablesportions_1", "vegetablesportions_2"
    ), c("vegetalfiber_1", "vegetalfiber_2"), c("solublefiber_1", 
    "solublefiber_2"), c("insolublefiber_1", "insolublefiber_2"
    ), c("lipids_1", "lipids_2"), c("lipidspc_1", "lipidspc_2"
    ), c("sfa_1", "sfa_2"), c("sfapc_1", "sfapc_2"), c("mufa_1", 
    "mufa_2"), c("mufapc_1", "mufapc_2"), c("pufa_1", "pufa_2"
    ), c("pufapc_1", "pufapc_2"), c("cholesterolintake_1", "cholesterolintake_2"
    )), v.names = c("age", "whz", "haz", "waz", "zbmi", "wc", 
"abc", "PA", "PAextra", "TVweekdays", "TVweekend", "kidmed", 
"totalcholesterol", "ldl", "hdl", "triglycerides", "glucose", 
"insuline", "hba1c", "homair", "fatmass", "energykcal", "protein", 
"proteinpc", "carbohydrates", "carbohydratespc", "sugar", "sugarpc", 
"starch", "fruitportions", "vegetablesportions", "vegetalfiber", 
"solublefiber", "insolublefiber", "lipids", "lipidspc", "sfa", 
"sfapc", "mufa", "mufapc", "pufa", "pufapc", "cholesterolintake"
), idvar = c("id", "group"), timevar = "time"), class = "data.frame")
```
````

Comment: … and the error message is?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? AFAIK, you must specify a formula with several predictors for a mutli-way ANOVA, not just with one predictor.

Comment: Error message: Error in `as_indices_impl()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
✖ Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
Backtrace:
  1. base::apply(finalds1[4:11], 2, anovatestpaired)
 31. rlang::cnd_signal(x)

Comment: I did a first analysis one way anova just to see the difference between groups but then I also want to include the time (two way repeated anova) because there are two time points to consider for each outcome variables between groups